# Slider doesn't fill 100% of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

So after I decided to remove a certain .css file that contained my menu, since I'm making a new one, there's this space/gab between the end of the screen to the left with the slider I have, like 5px wide. I haven't encountered this before, so I do not know where to look!

Comment: You did start your CSS of with a reset did you not ?

Answer (score 0):

Added `body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}` to my .css style sheet, fixed the problem!

Comment: You can shorten that to `body { margin: 0px; }`. It's the same thing but shorter.

Comment: Even better! It's only a school-project and won't be hosted, but will probably use it in the near-future as my website. Thanks!